# Allure+testng+gradle+jenkins не получается подключить к проекту

Tags: gradle, jenkins, testng, allure

Не получается получить отчет о тестах с помощью allure.С такими настройками build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.3"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version "2.3"
}

allure {
    version = '2.2.1'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = '2.0-BETA10'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.11'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.5.3'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
    compile 'com.beust:jcommander:1.72'
    compile 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'
}


task testContacts(type : Test) {
    useTestNG(){
        suites 'src/test/resources/testContacts.xml'
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('browser')){
        systemProperty 'browser', "${browser}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('target')){
        systemProperty 'target', "${target}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('verifyUi')){
        systemProperty 'verifyUi', "${verifyUi}"
    }

}
task testGroups(type : Test) {
    systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', 'build/allure-results'
    useTestNG(){
        suites 'src/test/resources/testGroups.xml'
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('browser')){
        systemProperty 'browser', "${browser}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('target')){
        systemProperty 'target', "${target}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('verifyUi')){
        systemProperty 'verifyUi', "${verifyUi}"
    }
}
```

тесты выполняются с командной строки, отчет генерируется в allure-report(даже добавляется скриншот), но при выполнении тестов в Jenkins вываливается ошибка:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'addressbook-web-tests'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskOutputs.files([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputFilePropertyBuilder;

Кроме того открыть отчет можно только с консоли командой allure open, в браузере выдает not found 404.

С настройками такими:

```
configurations {
    agent
}

apply plugin: 'java'
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.11'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.5.3'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
    compile 'com.beust:jcommander:1.72'
    compile 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'
    agent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10"
    compile "io.qameta.allure:allure-testng:2.0-BETA10"
}


task testContacts(type : Test) {
    systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', 'build/allure-results'
    useTestNG(){
        suites 'src/test/resources/testContacts.xml'
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('browser')){
        systemProperty 'browser', "${browser}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('target')){
        systemProperty 'target', "${target}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('verifyUi')){
        systemProperty 'verifyUi', "${verifyUi}"
    }

}
task testGroups(type : Test) {
    systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', 'build/allure-results'
    useTestNG(){
        suites 'src/test/resources/testGroups.xml'
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('browser')){
        systemProperty 'browser', "${browser}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('target')){
        systemProperty 'target', "${target}"
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('verifyUi')){
        systemProperty 'verifyUi', "${verifyUi}"
    }

    testGroups.doFirst {
        jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
    }
}
```

Тесты отрабатывают на Jenkins, вывод консоли такой:

```
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[addressbook-web-tests] $ cmd.exe /C "c:\Gradle\gradle-2.10\bin\gradle.bat clean testGroups && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJavaNote: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:processTestResources
:testClasses
:testGroups[AppClassLoader@5c647e05] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified


TestGroup > groupTests > ru.stqa.pft.addressbook.tests.GroupModificationTest.testGroupModification FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at GroupModificationTest.java:30

7 tests completed, 1 failed
:testGroups FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':testGroups'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/Admin/.jenkins/workspace/addressbook-test/addressbook-web-tests/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 56.896 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
[addressbook-test] $ c:\Allure\allure-2.4.1\bin\allure.bat generate -c -o C:\Users\Admin\.jenkins\workspace\addressbook-test\allure-report
allure-results does not exists
Report successfully generated to C:\Users\Admin\.jenkins\workspace\addressbook-test\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

но отчет allure пустой, хотя в папке allure-results есть json-файлы. Что я делаю неправильно?